# How can I use the Quick Chart Web Part with data from a Document Library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, library

I would like to use the Quick Chart Web Part with data from a Document Library not a list.

When I try to place a Quick Chart Web Part onto my page it only seems to be able to connect to a LIST or for values to be manually input.

I wish for the content to be taken from certain documents, tagged as Process Maps in my library and using column values from a column called FPMO

I’m using Sharepoint Online.

The document library is all text values

Comment: Could you be able to specify which SharePoint version is the target of your question? Please, add more information like the field types, chart type, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It’s by design that we can only get data from list but document library when us the quick chart web part in SharePoint Online.

As a workaround, you can use File View Web Part or Power BI  web part or embed code web part.

More information you can check the article: [4 ways to display charts in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/4-ways-to-display-charts-in-sharepoint/)